# PHP exec shell script return status 2

Tags: php, linux, shell, ssh, php-7

I want to execute shell script from my php application deployed on Red Hat linux server, I added this line to my application

```
exec("/app/sh/script.sh user server.info.com cmd.com 0 1 1" ,
         $ret_string,
         $ret_code);
```

the `$ret_code` is 2 I tried to run `/app/sh/script.sh user server.info.com cmd.com 0 1 1` on the server, it works fine there is no problem.

The content of the script /app/sh/script.sh is

```
ssh -x user@server.info.com . /app/sh/pro.sh user PRO; $EXE/cmd.com 0 1 1;
```

I tried to run another script that return just a string from my application and it works, so I think the problem on the ssh connection.

Why the script `script.sh` work when I call it from the server directly and not work when I call it from the php application ?

Comment: Does it make a difference what is in the shell code? Please make sure you reduce your scope to just include the problem. In other words, extract a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because when you execute a command through PHP, the user is the Apache user - usually **www-data** - and this user can't execute ssh command.

The Apache's user can't see your private key and it's a good idea!

Instead, you have to use a SSH class like Spatie package for example :

```
use Spatie\Ssh\Ssh;
    
$process = Ssh::create('user', 'example.com')->execute('your favorite command');
```

Have a look here : https://github.com/spatie/ssh

Comment: `this user can't execute ssh command` this isn’t true. Note that all that php lib does is [run the same command that is in the question](https://github.com/spatie/ssh/blob/main/src/Ssh.php#L145). As you go on to say, the apache user probably doesn’t have ssh keys that allow www-data to be identified (which also implies an alternative solution: set up keys for www-data) but that’s not the same thing as a user being unable to run a command. Relying on a convenience wrapper when it’s not strictly necessary isn’t generally a good idea - that just hides what is happening, and creates indirection.